# How to update chromedriver to the latest version on MacOS using homebrew?

Tags: macos, selenium-chromedriver, homebrew

My current version is `81.0.4044.69` and I want to update to the latest version `83.0.4103.39`

When I open Terminal and I do:
`brew cask install chromedriver`

It says:
`Warning: Cask 'chromedriver' is already installed.`

How can I update to the latest version `83.0.4103.39`?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Now you can also do:

```
brew update
brew upgrade chromedriver
```

or

```
brew update
brew upgrade --cask chromedriver
```

Also be aware that after each upgrade you will get again a system warning when using the `chromedriver` for the first time so you need to click `Cancel` in the warning and then go to "Preferences => Security & Privacy" and click "Allow Anyway" to accept the risk. Then on the next run, you'll have to click "Open" once.

> Note: The answer below was given for an older version and may not work anymore

I found out that I should do:

```
brew update
brew cask upgrade chromedriver
```

Another option is to uninstall and install it again like this:

```
brew cask uninstall chromedriver
==> Uninstalling Cask chromedriver
==> Unlinking Binary '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.
==> Purging files for version 81.0.4044.69 of Cask chromedriver

brew cask install chromedriver
==> Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/83.0.4103.39/chromedriver_mac64.zip
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'chromedriver'.
==> Installing Cask chromedriver
==> Linking Binary 'chromedriver' to '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'.
  chromedriver was successfully installed!
```

Now:

```
chromedriver --version
ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416})
```

Comment: Thank you, I come back to this answer like once a month XD

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend start using webdriver-manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

what I prefer mostly and use it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

with that package you should not worry about version of chromedriver, even though, you can even choose particular chrome driver version:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(version='86.0.4240.22').install())
```

it is not the solution of the ticket, but it makes live easier working with chromedriver

Answer (score 7):

I have recently have issues where I would receive a warning about chromedriver's developer not being trusted. To resolve this I use `brew info chromedriver` which gives the directory for chromedriver. Change into that directory and type `ls -l` and if the code like `drwxr-xr-x` has an @ at the end, that means your mac has quarantined that file. To pull it out of quarantine, type `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver`. Then you should be good to go.

Comment: if chrome driver 100.0.4896.60, then:
cd /usr/local/Caskroom/chromedriver/100.0.4896.60
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver

Comment: Simplest way to pull any chromedriver version from quaratine: `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine $(which chromedriver)`

Answer (score 6):

Uninstalling & installing the chromedriver worked -

```
brew uninstall chromedriver
brew install --cask chromedriver
```

Answer (score 3):

Now its just `brew upgrade chromedriver` no longer `cask`

Answer (score 3):

When I initially ran the following commands,

```
brew upgrade chromedriver 
brew upgrade --cask chromedriver 
brew uninstall chromedriver
```

I got the error below.

`Error: Cask 'chromedriver' is not installed.`

So I had to remove the chromedriver not managed by Homebrew first.

```
rm `which chromedriver`
```

After that, `brew install chromedriver` successfully installed the latest version.